# Jquery Call Back Object

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a simple call back feature. When a user selects a certain field, it will unselect all the fields above it. BUT if they unselect that field, it will revert back to it's original state.

So my HTML looks like this:

```
    <div id="check-container">

      <label class="margined-check"><input name="weekly" class="no-margin" type="checkbox"> <span class="margincheck bold">Weekly</span>   
      </label>

      <label class="margined-check"><input name="daily" class="no-margin" type="checkbox"> <span class="margincheck bold">Daily</span>
      </label>
      <label><input name="inPerson" class="no-margin type="checkbox"> <span class="margincheck bold">In-Person</span>

      </label>
      <label><input name="tracker" class="no-margin" type="checkbox"> <span class="margincheck bold">Track</span>

      </label>
      <label><input name="onCall" class="no-margin" type="checkbox"> <span class="margincheck bold">On Call</span>
      </label>
       </div>

   <div>
         <label><input name="clearAll" class="no-margin clearAll"type="checkbox"> <span class="margincheck bold">No Communication</span>
       </label>
       </div>
```

Then I am using this script:

```
 var CBback = {};
  $('.clearAll').change(function() {  

  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
  //call back object
  $(CBback).extend({
  Weekly: $("input[name='weekly']").(':checked'),
  Daily: $("input[name='Daily']").(':checked'),
  inPerson: $("input[name='inPerson']").(':checked'),
  Tracker: $("input[name='Tracker']").(':checked'),
  onCall: $("input[name='onCall']").(':checked')
  });

  //uncheck boxes
  $(this).parent().parent().find('#check-container).prop('checked', false);

  }
  else{
  //go through object and reassign values to inputs
  $.each(CBback, function(key, value){
   $("input[name='+key+').prop('checked, value);
  }





});
```

I am getting an error on '$(CBback).extend({' line saying there's an unexpected '('

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting to see your mistake.

Comment: `$("input[name='+key+')` should probably be `$('input[name='+key + ']')`. You're also missing another `'` around `prop('checked)`. `find('#check-container)` should also be `find('#check-container')` This is basic syntax checking.

Comment: Missing single quote at the end of #check-container

Comment: -1 Your code will throw errors in the dev tools. You need to CHECK THERE BEFORE posting on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were alot of syntax errors. In several spots you were using improper coding as well as missing quote marks and ending     });.

Here is your code now

```
var CBback = {};

$('.clearAll').change(function() {  

    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        //call back object
        $(CBback).extend({
            Weekly: $("input[name='weekly']:checked"),
            Daily: $("input[name='Daily']:checked"),
            inPerson: $("input[name='inPerson']:checked"),
            Tracker: $("input[name='Tracker']:checked"),
            onCall: $("input[name='onCall']:checked")
        });

        //uncheck boxes
        $(this).parent().parent().find('#check-container').prop('checked', false);

    }
    else{
        //go through object and reassign values to inputs
        $.each(CBback, function(key, value){
            $("input[name='+key+'").prop('checked', value);
        });
    }
});
```

In the future please try to check syntax. This can be done by inspecting your own code, or using an online tool such as http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php .

I hope this helps.